# 419 Page Expired после введения логина и пароля для входа в Voyager admin panel. Что делать?

Tags: php, laravel

Только что установил фреймворк laravel(хостинг reg.ru), настроил .env, миграции, потом require tcg/voyager, установка войажера с --dummy-data, создал админа, попытался войти в админку имя.сайта/admin, но после ввода имени пользователя/мейла и пароля выскакивает ошибка 419 Page Expired. Из-за чего и почему она появляется? Как исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите из того, что уже [есть](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com%20laravel%20419%20Page%20Expired&&lr=75). Добавьте в вопрос, что из этого пробовали и не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Из всего приличного количества ответов по этому вопросу на ресурсе, в моем случае, решение оказалось достаточно банальным: смена версии PHP с 7.3 на 7.2. (Laravel 5.8, Voyager).